# How to get pixel size/cell size of raster layer?

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis

After much searching, I've still not been able to figure out how to perform what seems like a simple function: I'd like to get the pixel size/cell size of a raster layer using PyQgis. Is there any native way to do this through QgsRasterLayer or a helper class? Or will I need to read the file in using GDAL functions, e.g.:

```
geotransform = dataset.GetGeoTransform()
if not geotransform is None:
    print 'Pixel Size = (',geotransform[1], ',',geotransform[5],')'
```

Thanks for your help.

Alex

Comment: What format are your rasters in? It is often possible to parse the resolution out of a raster's header.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You tagged your question with pyqgis. Here is a small solution using the Pyqgis modules

```
...
# assuming ras is a QgsRasterLayer object
pixelSizeX = ras.rasterUnitsPerPixelX()
pixelSizeY = ras.rasterUnitsPerPixelY()
```

Comment: Classic. The docs just need to have "(cell size)" added to the description of those two methods!

Answer (score 0):

To spell this one out in 2023, this code worked for me:

```
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer

ras = QgsRasterLayer('D:/Bigboy.tif')
pixelSizeX = ras.rasterUnitsPerPixelX()
pixelSizeY = ras.rasterUnitsPerPixelY()
print(pixelSizeX)
print(pixelSizeY)
```